# Is it ever possible to get the current (member) function name in C++?

Tags: c++

I don’t know much about RTTI, but I believe that thanks to that you can retrieve the name of variables at run-time. 
Is it possible to retrieve the name of the function the thread is currently running ?

Comment: No, RTTI doesn't return the **name** of variables, it allows you to determine their **type**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one grab a stack trace in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c)

Comment: Alright, I thought `typeid(var).name` was doing that but apparently it returns the name of the type of the variable.

Comment: Why would you even care?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Debug information.

Comment: It could be debug information. In my case I want to make wrapper functions: from a shared object A.so, I want a function foo to call the same function foo on another shared object B.so I would have opened.

Comment: @victor the result of `typeid(var).name` is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C++11 standardized `__func__` for the current function.

Various compilers support variations of `__FUNCTION__`, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, and others.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing GNU compatible stuffs, you may want to try [backtrace](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html).

Comment: Yes, but it is more GNU libc (or Linux) related than C++ or g++ specific.

Answer (score 0):

No.

C++'s [run-time type identification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) allows you to figure out the type of an object, but not the name of the method you're currently in.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. C++ does not support reflection (neither static nor dynamic) (like e.g. C#). You would need some preprocessor magic to emulate that.

Apart from that, there is not necessarily a notion of a function/method name during run-time (this only available as debugging information if you compiled your sources with the corresponding flags).